# Getting error while running clubbed swift & react-native project on iOS device

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, facebook, react-native

I have an existing project written on swift and I have integrated react native to it everything is working fine on simulator but while running on device it give an error ie-

Could not connect to the development server.
Ensure

node server is running and available on the same network - run npm start from the react native root

node server URL is correctly set in AppDelegate

I have tried most of the method discuss over here
[github link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/304)

like changing the localhost to my laptop IP,

connecting device and laptop on the same network

but still i could not able to solve it, if i am missing any things kindly enlighten on comment or answer you valuable time will always be helpful

thank you

Comment: is your lapton and device in same network?

Comment: yes @Codesingh I have tried that always, other react native standalone project are working fine what wrong in clubbed project idk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note:-
Only for project which uses both swift code and react-native code

Xcode 8x swift 3x

As a clubbed project which consists of swift and react-native follow the step to run it on the device:-

Open Xcode

Navigate to TARGETS > Build Phases > click on (+)add button

click on New Run Script Phase

In place of

```
Type a script or drag a script file from your workspace to insert its path
```

place this

```
export NODE_BINARY=node

/{your project directory }/js/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-native-xcode.sh
```

change source URL

from this

> return URL(string:"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios")

to this

> this - return Bundle.main.url(forResource: "main", withExtension: "jsbundle")

when you will run the project it will generate an offline .js bundle and fetch all data from that

while running the project make sure you watch the report navigator check if script run successfully or not like the image below
[image: successfull script run]

if everything is ok it will run on the device as well as simulator

resource used from solving [raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/136047/react-native-existing-app)